# Viewing Contents of datastore in Powerbuilder

Tags: debugging, powerbuilder, datastore

I am running powerbuilder 11.2 and trying to debug an operation that pulls data from a text file into a datastore.  I can set a watch on the datastore and see information about it,  but I want to see the actual contents of the datastore.  I have seen some suggestions of adding an expression to the watch window and I inserted the following command:

```
[datastore].saveas("c:\test\[datastore].xls", xls!,true)
```

into the watch window but all I got was a circle with a line through it in red.  I checked the directory and nothing was saved.  I haven't done PB development in a long, long time and this was assigned to me because I did PB development before.  So, how can I dump the contents of a datastore in debug mode?  Any and all help is so very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the `saveas()` tip is a quick way to check what is in a datastore.

But you do not have to add the expression in a watch (because it is likely to replace the data each time the watch is evaluated, or to crash if the datastore is not valid) but in the "quick watch" dialog.

1. put a breakpoint after the datastore is supposed to be populated (e.g. after a `retrieve()` or `importString()`)
2. run your program
3. when the BP triggers, you can make a "right-click / QuickWatch" on the datastore name to display the Quick Watch dialog
4. replace the `yourdatastore` in the expression field by `yourdatastore.saveas("c:\temp\somefile.xls", excel5!, true)` then click "reevaluate"
5. if the export is successful you should see in the Quick Watch dialog that the returned value is `1`. `-1` tells there is a problem, like a wrong path or the result file already opened (locked).

You can also use `text!` instead of the `excel5!` value to see the data if Office is not installed in that box. `excel5!` is a pretty old format that is widely known by viewers, but `excel8!` or `xlsx!` (after PB11.5.1) is equally acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

If your location to write the file is c:\test the syntax is "c:\test\"

So the proper entry in the watch window would be:

```
ids_mydata.saveas("c:\test\mydata.xls", Excel!, true)
```

This saves the data currently in the 'ids_mydata' datastore to an Excel file named 'mydata.xls' in the folder 'test' on your C drive.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your expression. Save as type Excel must be `Excel!` or `XLSX!`.

**Saving as Excel 2007 and later (requires .NET 3.5 or later):**

```
[datastore].saveas("c:\test[datastore].xlsx", xlsx!,true)
```

**Saving as Excel format:**

```
[datastore].saveas("c:\test[datastore].xls", Excel!,true)
```

Comment: Okay I guess I am not getting this right.  I am trying to enter this expression into the watch window by doing a right click then selecting Insert.  Then the new expression box appears and I type in the code above changing the datastore and still get the red circle with a line through it.  Is this the wrong place, if so, how do I get to the window to enter this expression?  Sorry I am so amateur at this, but like I said it was 15 years ago.  Thanks.

Comment: Is DataStore instantiated?

Answer (score 0):

The SaveAs is not a debugger watch expression. You have to add it to your code and put a breakpoint on the line following it. When it hits the breakpoint, open the file in Excel.

Comment: I put in an enhancement request to allow for viewing datastore contents from the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You might find it helpful. The [link](http://www.angelfire.com/home/jasonvogel/pb_technique_data_and_dot_notation.html#single_data_item) explains how to access data from different buffers.

Anytime during debug you see the red circle in watch window where you evaluate expression, that means your app crashed already. You have to restart debugger.

Better use TRY CATCH statement (and that does not prevent from crashing in debugger i guess).

Comment: the easy way to see DataStore contents is copy data from DS to DW Control. Avoid using debugger when you can do things easy and quick way.